# Drupal - Creating my own view

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I have been looking around online for a little while now and have been unable to find something that has worked for me or has explained what I need in a more clear matter. I am looking to create my own view that will display content that I have stored.

I know that I can do this with the views module, but I need a bit more to add to it and I was wondering if maybe one of you would be able to assist with making this clearer. I need to display all of my content titles that I have stored, but have them display in alphabetical order based off of the last name. Again, this is easy to do in the Drupal Views module, but I still need more. I need to have each content print inside of a div tag based on the alphabetical order. So all of the contents with the last name of `A` would be in a div tag with `id = "a"` and so on.

This I could most likely figure out to do on my own perhaps, but I don't know how to get to the opportunity to set up my own custom view to begin with. I feel like I have been looking for a while. Would anyone be able to help me?

```
<div id="a-content">
    Johnny Appleseed
    Joe Alastname
</div>
<div id="b-content">
    Billy Bob
    Greg Bohman
    Steve Brochachi
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that come to my mind...

1. Base upon the Glossary View that comes disabled by default when installing the Views module. This will display all your titles or view items within an **alphabetical pager**, and you could build on it.
2. If you need to display titles + any other fields alphabetically on the same page, you could do the following:

   - Do your 'titles' view unformatted list (you could even add more fields into it).
   - Add the Node Title field again, and crop the length of the display to only the first character.
   - Be sure to sort the list upon the Title field.
   - On the Views options, group your list upon that hidden field. The result would be all titles or node names wrapped inside a div with the initial character.

Hope this gets you on your way.

Comment: I have tried using the Glossary View, but I do not see a way that I would be able to display the content in div tags going that route. I also need all the content to be displayed at all times and then have the alphabetical links drop down to where the letter is. I have edited my original question to help explain what i mean better. Do you still think that the second option would work?

Comment: Yes! The second option would work for your needs. For the DIV id, you could overwrite the output of the wrapper DIV and craft the name using the field token (something like '[node-title2]') corresponding to the grouping field.

Comment: I am afraid you have lost me with what you are saying. How would I be able to add the content into a `<div>` tag through adding a new field? Sorry if this is a silly question, this is my first time trying to customize a view with Drupal.

Comment: No worries. If you the instructions of the second option, you will end with a list of titles wrapped into divs grouped by the initial letters (as in an index). In your edited questions you also want that initial letter to be added into each div's ID. For doing so you can a) run a .each() jQuery loop in the grouping div, fetch de initial character and add craft an ID attr using that char, or b) use the 'Rewrite field' option in Views for the grouping field and add the div tag and ID using the field's output with a token/replacement pattern (all this only makes sense following the 2nd option).

Comment: How do I get to the `Rewrite field` option inside my view? And once I am inside there would I be doing the rewriting with php?

Comment: When configuring the field, you get the chance to `REWRITE RESULTS`on the field options. There you can rewrite the output via wildcards like this: http://www.mediafire.com/view/o07jy461srnvsbn

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense, but how do you go about `1)` trimming everything out but the first letter for the id? `2)` Instead of using the content field i want to use the last name field i have for the div tag id, how would i call that field? `3)` by doing what you have in your picture, it would put each one in its own id, I want each name to be in the same div tag id as the other ones with the last name starting with its alphabetical letter. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: 1) In the field's configuration options, there's an option for cropping the output length, just put '1' as the value. You can set the field as 'hidden' and still use it as the grouping field (for this to work as expected you should sort the list alphabetically on the Sort section of your View). 2) You can use any field you defined in the Content Type, the Title is just an example. 3)I'm afraid the procedure described **inserts** the capital letters and markup instead of wrapping sub-lists, but you could manipulate the output with jQuery to rewrite the view and display as you wish.

Comment: I think what i might end up doing is manipulating the view's theme with php and JSON. But I will have to see how that goes first. I really appreciate all of your help and I will be sure to comment back and let you know how it all goes.

Comment: Great. Perhaps you should edit the question's title so more people can find help about the topic. Cheers.